# Millenial Media [5]: [LOAD_FAILED] No additional details available

Tags: android, millennial-media

I am trying to implement ads into an android app with Millenial Media SDK Version 6.  I followed the instructions for integrating with Android at http://docs.millennialmedia.com/android-ad-sdk/inline-ads.html.

But I get an error in adb logcat:

> [5]: [LOAD_FAILED] No additional details available.

And the ad doesn't show up.

I found some documentation that mentions the error at http://docs.millennialmedia.com/android-ad-sdk/apidocs/classcom_1_1millennialmedia_1_1_inline_ad_1_1_inline_error_status.html, but there is no description on what this error means.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out by adding a line:

```
MMLog.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
```

To my code and then using

```
adb logcat | grep MMSDK
```

The output explained the problem, and it wasn't hard to understand.  Hopefully this answer helps someone else.

Comment: Hi, can you please share more info - what was the problem you found from looking at the log, and how you resolved it? Thanks

Comment: @ShimonShnitzer It was a dependency problem - class not found or something.  I fixed it by changing my build script from ant to gradle.

Comment: Hi again. Could not find the resolve for this. Can you please give me more details - what was missing? how did you fix it? TIA

Comment: @ShimonShnitzer I was using the jar directly from the MMSDK, it works much better if you switch to gradle because it automatically links everything up for you - unlike ant.  If you've already switched can you share what error you got with `adb logcat | grep MMSDK` while running your app on an emulator or device?  If I remember correctly I was having trouble finding the correct version of google-play-services which is a dependency of the MMSDK.  I don't think it succeeded in finding a certain class ( which class it was I don't remember ).

Comment: Thanks so much for your continuous support!